# Correct pronunciation when a syllable ends with two consonants

Tags: pronunciation

When a syllable ends with two consonants, such as 헑 or 닭, which do you pronounce?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ㄹ is silent in these cases.

Source: 흙 [is pronounced](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=43838600) 흑. 닭 [is pronounced](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=8804500) 닥. So on and so forth.

Comment: This answer doesn't paint the entire picture and is true only in some circumstances. In 읽다 the 읽 is pronounced as 익, whereas in 읽어요 the 읽 is fully pronounced. To put it another way, 읽다 is pronounced as 익다, whereas is pronounced as 일거요.

Answer (score 11):

With the following pairs, the first consonant is pronounced:

**ㄳ, ㄵ, ㅄ, ㄼ, ㄽ, ㄾ, + any with ㅎ (ㄶ, ㅀ)**

- 앉다 -> 안는다,
- 여덟 -> 여덜
- 핥다 -> 할다

With the following pairs, the second consonant is pronounced:

**ㄺ, ㄻ, ㄿ**

- 흙 -> 흑
- 삶 -> 삼
- 읊다 -> 읍다 [읍따]

There are a few exceptions to these:

- 밟다 -> 밥다 [밥따]
- 맑게 -> 말게 [말께] (but 맑다 -> 막다)

Reference:

이익섭, 이상억, 채완 (1997), "한국의 언어", 서울: 신구문화사.

Comment: 핥다, not 햝다........

Answer (score 3):

There are certainly rules to pronounce those double consonants, as @gaeguri answered. Yet there are many interesting pronunciation rules when they combines to other words. (I'm not a linguistic expert.)

When `닭`, for example, comes with `~을`, the `ᆨ` moved and the word `닭을` pronounces `달글`.

```
닭을[달글] 쫓다. Chases a Chicken.
```

`삶`, similarly with `~을`, pronounces `살믈`.

```
삶을[살믈] 살다. (Live a Life)
```

...

```
앉아[안자]주세요. (Please have a sit)
```